# Collection in order and synchronized-Java

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

I just want to use a collection that gives me the items by the order I added them in the past, and also is synchronized. Of course I want to add-remove items dynamically. I am so confused by the many collections Java has. If anyone knows the answer please tell me.

Answer (score 5):

Well, [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) has the two properties you asked for... but to be honest, I don't find that the collection being synchronized is *actually* that useful. I find it's rarely useful to just make *single* operations synchronized - instead, you want to synchronize over a whole set of operations, such as iterating over the whole collection.

But if for whatever reason you really, really want a collection where each operation is individually synchronized, `Vector` will do the trick.

Or you could use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and create a synchronized wrapper using [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: ok I used it and it worked, but i have a question. I declared it like this: java.util.List<Post> c = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Post>()); but if i want to cast an object (which is like this list) to assign it to an list i declared, how am i gonna do that? this doesn't work: java.util.List<Post> c =request.getAttribute("posts");
       Iterator<Post> i = c.iterator();  
       Post p=(Post)i.next();

Comment: I used vector succesfully in the end. When i put the synchronization in the creating time, i get serious error. Where should i put the synchronization?

Comment: @Vlenorroia: It's unclear what you mean, to be honest. We'd have to see the code - and the error, ideally. If you're still interested in solving that part, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What about ConcurrentLinkedDeque? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html

It is fully synchronized and offers the required FIFO order of a queue.